# Grab NSString from Parse.com and paste it into UILabel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, parse-platform

I'd like to grab a NSString from the Parse.com and paste it into a Label in my iOS App.

Does anyone know how to do so ?
I'm having massive problems with it :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code, links, documentation, anything?

Comment: documention: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide

Comment: What problems are you having? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The counter-question is "Which NSString do you want to get"? I assume it's some property of a PFObject that you want to display, right?
What makes this property so interesting?

Let's say you want to display the *title* of a *Book* whose *author* is *Hemmingway*.

First you want to find the object:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Book"];  // I want to find a book
[query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"Hemmingway"];       // authored by hemmingway
PFObject *book = [query findFirstObject];               // go get it!
```

Then you just read its properties with `objectForKey`

```
myLabel.text = [book objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Check out the [iOS guides](http://parse.com/docs/ios_guide) for more advanced questions. If you plan to display many properties of many PFObjects, you might want to check out the [PFQueryTableViewController](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables)