# Paste NSString from parse into UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing, uilabel

I'd like to grab the NSString which I created on parse.com and paste it into a label, if the view loads. I tried this [Grab NSString from Parse.com and paste it into UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776809/grab-nsstring-from-parse-com-and-paste-it-into-uilabel) but It doesnt seems to work. Does have anyone a solution for my problem?

I've set up something at parse here:

[image]

and also tried this code. However, NOTHING works...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TextObject"];

PFObject *textu = [query getObjectWithId:@"zhfk6bWd5r"];
label.text = [textu objectForKey:@"text"];
```

I would be glad it someone could help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work? Does the text not show up? Does it throw an exception? What comes out (if anything) in your console? Have you tried setting breakpoints and inspecting the values of `query` and `textu`?

Comment: with the first one from the other thred I get an error with the firstObject... and the second doesnt seems to work

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Isn't the label updating? You should be careful with running querys on the mainthread.

Comment: It shows nothing the label is empty

Comment: +1 for the well explained question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is `TestObject` in the image but `TextObject` in the code.
Please change the code to:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
PFObject *textu = [query getObjectWithId:@"zhfk6bWd5r"];
label.text = [textu objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: @NoahRaissi: sorry that was my mistake, I just edited my answer.

Comment: NOO u missunderstood U helped me!!! you showed me my spelling mistake!! Thanks a lot! I've gave u thumbs up!

Comment: I cant accept it because of the other users they will missunderstood whats the right an wrong so I posted my solution

Comment: hmm copy the code of my awnser below in yours than I will mark it as correct

Comment: I had edited my answer about 10 minutes ago, please check my comments that was posted about 10 minutes ago. Thanks no need of accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

The spelling was incorect so here's my solution:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];

PFObject *textu = [query getObjectWithId:@"zhfk6bWd5r"];
label.text = [textu objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Thanks to all!